# Laplace form for a function

Tags: calculus

How can I resolve this using Laplace transform L[$\dot{x}$(s)] = ?

I must have the result s(x) - s(0)...

I have tried using integral from zero to infinity from $e^{-st}$ $\cdot$ $\dot{x(t)}$ and than I am stucked.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\mathcal{L}[\dot x(t)]=\int_0^{\infty}\dot x (t)e^{-st}dt=\left [x (t)e^{-st}\right ]_0^{\infty}+s\int_0^{\infty} x (t)e^{-st}dt \\ =\left [x (\infty)e^{-s\cdot\infty}-x (0)e^{-s\cdot0}\right ]+s\int_0^{\infty} x (t)e^{-st}dt=-x (0)+s\int_0^{\infty} x (t)e^{-st}dt \\ =-x (0)+sX(s)$$

where $X(s)=\mathcal{L}[x(t)]$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$L[x(s)] := \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} x(t) dt $$ and we want to find $L[x'(s)]$. We can proceed by taking the above integral and integrating by parts. We take $u = x(t)$ and $dv = e^{-st} dt$, and we find the corresponding values $du = x'(t) dt$ and $v = -\frac{1}{s} e^{-st}$, so our integral becomes $$L[x(s)] = - \frac{x(t)}{s}e^{-st}\bigg|_{t=0}^{t=\infty} + \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x'(t)}{s} e^{-xt} dt = \frac{x(0)}{s} + \frac{1}{s} L[x'(s)]  $$ and we can rearrange this equation to tell us that $$\boxed{L[x'(s)] = s \: L[x(s)] - x(0)} $$